# Wifi not working well in Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, 22.04, realtek

**Please someone help me solve this**

I'm using ubuntu with dual boot with windows, and i have a problem with wifi connection in the linux distro.
basicaly all wifi networks show on the windows side and working good, but in ubuntu only one wifi network that is mine ( less than 1m in distance ) is showing, i don't know what is the problem, here some output of commands that i use :

```
lspci
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
09:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

```
lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 07
       serial: 50:65:f3:08:84:d6
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2600000-b2600fff memory:b2400000-b2403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlp9s0f0
       version: 00
       serial: ac:d1:b8:5e:c8:09
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic firmware=0.37 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:b2510000-b251ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

```
uname -r
5.19.0-32-generic
```

Comment: You might need these drivers for that Wi-Fi card:  https://github.com/Borwe/rt3290-linux-drivers

Comment: ...or may be, the undetected networks transmit in the 5GHz range, and the card in question is, apparently, 2.4GHz.

Comment: @mikewhatever but when i boot into windows everything works fine

Comment: @Terrance thanks sir, i well try this.